# Expanding / Resolving ~ in node.js

Tags: node.js, path

I am new to nodejs. Can node resolve ~ (unix home directory) example ~foo, ~bar
to /home/foo, /home/bar

```
> path.normalize('~mvaidya') 
'~mvaidya'
> path.resolve('~mvaidya') 
'/home/mvaidya/~mvaidya'
>
```

This response is wrong; I am hoping that ~mvaidya must resolve to /home/mvaidya

Answer (score 50):

As [QZ Support](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3196753/qz-support) noted, you can use `process.env.HOME` on OSX/Linux. Here's a simple function with no dependencies.

```
const path = require('path');
function resolveHome(filepath) {
    if (filepath[0] === '~') {
        return path.join(process.env.HOME, filepath.slice(1));
    }
    return filepath;
}
```

Comment: This erroneously resolves `~foo` to `/home/<current-user>/foo` when technically it should resolve to `/home/foo` (at least in zsh).

Comment: Instead of `process.env.HOME`, perhaps should use `require('os').homedir()`?

Answer (score 22):

The reason this is not in Node is because `~` expansion is a `bash` (or shell) specific thing. It is unclear how to escape it properly. See [this comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/684#issuecomment-72344577) for details.

There are various libraries offering this, most just a few lines of code...

- https://npm.im/untildify ; doesn't do much more than `os.homedir()`, see [index.js#L10](https://github.com/sindresorhus/untildify/blob/master/index.js#L10)
- https://npm.im/expand-tilde ; basically uses `os-homedir` to achieve the same, see [index.js#L12](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/expand-tilde/blob/master/index.js#L12)
- https://npm.im/tilde-expansion ; this uses `etc-passwd` so doesn't seem very cross platform, see [index.js#L21](https://github.com/bahamas10/node-tilde-expansion/blob/master/index.js#L21)

So you probably want to do this yourself.

Comment: appreciate the background explanation, that `~` is a bash-thing.

Comment: os.homedir() is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

This NodeJS library supports this feature via an async callback. It uses the etc-passswd lib to perform the expansion so is probably not portable to Windows or other non Unix/Linux platforms.

- https://www.npmjs.org/package/tilde-expansion
- https://github.com/bahamas10/node-tilde-expansion

If you only want to expand the home page for the **current user** then this lighter weight API may be all you need. It's also synchronous so simpler to use and works on most platforms.

- https://www.npmjs.org/package/expand-home-dir

**Examples:**

```
 expandHomeDir = require('expand-home-dir')

 expandHomeDir('~')
 // => /Users/azer

 expandHomeDir('~/foo/bar/qux.corge')
 // => /Users/azer/foo/bar/qux.corge
```

Another related lib is home-dir that returns a user's home directory on any platform:

```
https://www.npmjs.org/package/home-dir
```

Comment: For those OK with the current home directory on Linux/Unix/Mac, `process.env.HOME` seems to work swimmingly well in place of the node module solutions mentioned in other posts.  e.g. `~/somepath` can be `process.env.HOME + '/somepath'`, warning however...  it won't solve the original question of `~someuserhome/somepath` as that would need the module solutions linked.

Answer (score 13):

An example:

`const os = require("os");`

`"~/Dropbox/sample/music".replace("~", os.homedir)`

Comment: This will create an incorrect path if your path contains ~ anywhere other than the beginning of the string

Answer (score 12):

This is a combination of some of the previous answers with a little more safety added in.

```js
/**
 * Resolves paths that start with a tilde to the user's home directory.
 *
 * @param  {string} filePath '~/GitHub/Repo/file.png'
 * @return {string}          '/home/bob/GitHub/Repo/file.png'
 */
function resolveTilde (filePath) {
  const os = require('os');
  if (!filePath || typeof(filePath) !== 'string') {
    return '';
  }

  // '~/folder/path' or '~' not '~alias/folder/path'
  if (filePath.startsWith('~/') || filePath === '~') {
    return filePath.replace('~', os.homedir());
  }

  return filePath;
}
```

- Is a simple helper function that can be called from anywhere.
- Uses more modern `os.homedir()` instead of `process.env.HOME`.
- Has basic type checking. You may want to default to returning `os.homedir()` if a non-string is passed in instead of returning empty string.
- Verifies that path starts with `~/` or is just `~`, to not replace other aliases like `~stuff/`.
- Uses a simple "replace first instance" approach, instead of less intuitive `.slice(1)`.

Answer (score 9):

I just needed it today and the only less-evasive command was the one from the `os`.

```
$ node
> os.homedir()
'/Users/mdesales'
```

I'm not sure if your syntax is correct since ~ is already a result for the home dir of the current user

Answer (score 1):

Today I used https://github.com/sindresorhus/untildify

I run on OSX, worked well.