# fs-path does not seem to be creating correct files/folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

All console.logs are running but the folder and files are not being created at all. What am I doing wrong?

you can assume everything with `this` is defined

```js
  public writeFiles = () => {
    console.log('writing files');
    const folderPath = `~/dev/generated-projects/${this.projectName}/server/api/routes/${this.structure.name}`;
    console.log('folder path', folderPath);
    fsPath.writeFileSync(path.join(folderPath, 'index.ts'), this.indexFile);
    fsPath.writeFileSync(path.join(folderPath, 'routes.ts'), this.routesFile);
    fsPath.writeFileSync(path.join(folderPath, 'helpers.ts'), this.helperFile);
    console.log('create routes for ', this.structure.name);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is a shell-ism. You need to expand it [Expanding / Resolving ~ in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077670/expanding-resolving-in-node-js) or use `process.env.HOME` directly.